# Issue with DateTime.Parse method in EU salesforce Instances

Tags: apex, debugging, debug-logs

```
String dtTimeStr1='10/14/2011 11:46 AM';
DateTime dtTime= DateTime.parse(dtTimeStr1);
```

The above piece of code runs successfully in NA instances but in EU instances it throws an error `Invalid date/time: 10/14/2011 11:46 AM`.

Anyone came across the same issue.

To be specific: It works in instance `na33`.

It throws the above error in `eu11`.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation of the [DateTime class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) the `.parse(string)` method expects the string to be in the local time zone and also formatted to the running user's locale.

> **parse(datetimeString)**
>
> Constructs a Datetime from the given String in the local time zone and
>   in the format of the user locale.

The documentation also includes this note:

> You may need to change the format of the date string if you have a different locale.